# MongoDB (3.2) PHP Driver v1.1 doesn't install on PHP 5.5

Tags: mongodb

I have installed Windows Server 2008 64-bit, without SSL support for Windows 10 & I saw that the version of that is 3.2 ...
So I wanted to download MongoDB PHP Driver, I saw that I should download PHP Driver DLLs that are 1.1 or more. I downloaded that latest one for PHP 5.5 with Safe Thread (It is enabled in my PHP). I put it in (ext) folder & I wrote extension=php_mongodb.dll in PHP.ini ... But When I run phpinfo() function, It doesn't show MongoDB in extensions.
**I have searched & tried very much but It didn't work, So I asked here.**

Comment: Have you tried steps in [MongoDB PHP installation Windows](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.windows) ? Also see [FAQ: How do I add PHP directory to the PATH on Windows](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.addtopath)

Comment: @WanBachtiar Hi, First, Thanks for your response ...
I went to PATH & I saw that I have added PHP Folder ...
E:\Wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12 But It doesn't work ...